Outdoor LED power PCB schematic review
Could someone look over my schematic and let me know if I need to change anything or if everything looks good? This PCB will be used outside (inside a waterproof cover) and will power a few LED strips that I put on an umbrella. Saved room by mounting the ESP32 and 5 to 12 V converter (XL6009) in the vertical position.
I also have a temperature monitor that also connects to the ESP32 via the I2C connections.





It looks like a safety hazard. Can you describe how you expect the XL6009  module to work if it is connected like that?

if you're turning 5v into 12v to run several strips, that's going to be a lot of current on the 5v supply (~2.5x the 12v current). It looks like you're using one of those little hilink 5v "transformers", and those would only provide enough power for a few dozen dim 12v pixels.

@dandavis Even though I'm using the 5v to 12v XL6009 that has a current limit of 4 amps and 10W? I would think that would be enough to drive the LEDs just fine as before I made a custom PCB i ran them from a normal wall wort that was 3a.

@Justme there are 2 test points (out_neg1 and in_neg1) that I will solder my wires to and then extend them to the other pins (2 & 4) that are vertical away from the board. Pins 1 and 3 are being soldered to pin headers on the PCB itself (to also help to keep it vertical).

if the 6009 is 100% efficient, that's 1.6a@12v available, which at 60ma per pixel is ~28 pixels. Are you sure your 5v supply can provide 4A though? Those hilink PSUs are usually about half an amp... My main point is that it would be a lot better to supply 12v from the AC and buck down to 5v for the MCU.

@StealthRT Exactly, the boost module input ground pin connects nowhere. That's why I am asking.
